# jQuery Isotope and Mosaic Merge Solution

Tags: jquery, mosaic

I'm trying to create something that looks like the following [website](http://www.cla-ude.net/)

Essentially what I'm after is to use Isotope in order create a portfolio page with lots of thumbnail. Once a user hovers over a thumbnail, a caption overlay will appear(fade in) and then when the user clicks on the thumbnail, a large version of the photo will appear. The layout is going to rearrange.

So far I've managed to work with a couple of plugins to achieve the effect separately... in other words I've used Mosiac.js to achieve the hover effect and Isotope.js to achieve the layout. You can see what I have so far on [mosaic.html](http://jquery.ramiyahya.com/mosaic.html) and [isotope.html](http://jquery.ramiyahya.com/isotope.html)

I'm stuck though. I can't figure out how to combine these two solutions. I've tried working with the CSS classes and fiddled a little with jQuery. I'm a jQuery newb :(

Please help!

Let me know if you need any more info or question is unclear

Answer (score 2):

No need to use mosaic.js for something simple as this. First, get your website working with Isotope in terms of functionality; don't worry about design fine-tuning at that stage. Then, just nest some div(s) with overlay caption(s) in your Isotope elements and hide them by default. Attach a hover event to your Isotope elements that shows the hidden div(s) and reveal them when the viewer's mouse is over an Isotope element.

Remember though, people with mobile touch screen devices will not see your hover effects...

HTML

```
<div class="item">
    // content of the Isotope .item
    <div class="overlay">
        // content of the overlay
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.overlay {
    display: none;
    /* other rules to style the overlay */
}
```

jQuery

```
$(".overlay").hover(function(){
    $(this).filter(':not(:animated)').animate({ whatever you like to animate });
        }, function() {
    $(this).animate({ whatever you like to animate });
});
```

See also [the jQuery fadeToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/) and [the jQuery animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) methods as well as the show(), hide(), etc. methods for the effect you may like to implement on hover.

Comment: I got it to work the way I wanted yet still there's a small thing I'd like your help with... Please see [link](jquery.ramiyahya.com) If you notice, on click to display large image, the black overlay disappears from all the photos. I'd like to make this disappear only on the large image. I believe it's something to do with $(this) selector ... not sure how to do that.

Comment: You may remove this line of code almost at the end "$overlay.removeClass();" but then, because you define your mouseover/hover behaviour outside the event handler for each element, exiting an enlarged image with the mouse would then still black out that large image. i'd put the hover() logic inside the conditional, so you can define: only small/preview images have the .overlay removed on hover; the large images have the .overlay class toggled and the hover() effect removed so moving the mouse out of a large image does not "blacken" it.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me... I'd really appreciate it if you could help with coding what you suggested... I can't get my head around the logic.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same and can't figure out why I cannot combine them. Mosaic requires a height and isotope has that dynamic. so I use:

```
$('.mosaic-block').each(function (index) {
    $(this).height($(this).find(".mosaic-backdrop").height());
});
```

but Isotope still has items placed over it and the caption still does not work. But this might point you in the right direction if you want to stick with Mosaic. I am going to convert my code to the solution of @Systembolagnet. Please accept his answer